# How to avoid using redundant words like "not so", "quite" or "sort of"?

Tags: nuance

Today I find an interesting table in [Writers Write](http://writerswrite.co.za/45-ways-to-avoid-using-the-word-very):

[image]

I wonder do we have the same table, but for the words "not so", "quite", "sort of", etc?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need another table to help you accomplish this; **it's a mindset change**.

Take the words *hot* and *large*, for example. The table suggests:

- *scalding* instead of *very hot*
- *colossal* instead of *very large*

but one could have found either of these words by using a thesaurus, along with even more alternatives:

> **hot** *scalding, scorching, sizzling, blistering, torrid*, etc.
> **large** *colossal, gigantic, enormous, mountainous, vast*, etc.

In a similar way, I can think of synonyms for *sort of hot* or *not so large*, and go back to my trusty thesaurus for more alternatives:

> sort of hot = **warm** ⇒ *toasty, heated, summery*, etc.
> not so hot = **lukewarm** ⇒ *tepid, warmish, cool*, etc.
>
> sort of large = **big** ⇒ *sizable, substantial, significant,* etc.
> not so large = **moderate** ⇒ *modest, average, medium,* etc.

Most importantly, though, that table is of limited use anyhow. It's not meant to be a cure-all, it's meant to give you an **idea** of better words you can use. Your writing would suffer if you always substituted *colossal* for *very large*, while ignoring words like *mammoth* or *stupendous*. Moreover, these words can be applied in several ways, and that table only offers a synonym for one of each. For example, if I'm using a word like *big* or *large*, I can be speaking of:

- a very big shoe (which I might call *huge*)
- a very big shopping center (which I might call *colossal*)
- a very big day (which I might call *momentous*)
- a very big galaxy (which I might call *expansive*)
- a very big celebrity (who I might call *renowned*)

A word like *squalid* works great for a *very dirty* apartment, but I wouldn't use it for a *very dirty* car. I can't imagine myself ever describing a *very hot* fire by using the word *scalding*.

In short, you don't need more tables – you need for that one table to do what it was intended to do:

- spark a desire to use more descriptive language,
- help you recognize when your own writing is trite, and
- illustrate how to improve banal word choices.

Comment: It is also worth saying, though most of us know it already, that there is no reason to always avoid using _very X_ in favour of some other word. Variation and appropriateness is the key (or one of the many keys, at least) to good writing, and _very X_ has its place just like anything else. For example, I may say that something _very clever_ is _brilliant_, _outstanding_, _genius_, _ingenious_, _creative_, _bright_, etc.; but I’m wanting to be sarcastic to someone who’s just realised that 2 + 2 = 4, I’ll definitely be going for, “Yes dear, that’s very clever of you. Now eat your soup.”.

Comment: Just to expand on one of your examples, compare a "filthy car" with a "squalid car" (which I am claiming you can use). Where is the dirt? With the same noun the strong synonymous adjective chosen can significantly affect the image created.

Comment: @ChrisH And likewise, if you have two extremely dirty cars, one a 2014 Mercedes and the other a 1984 Fiat 500, which one is the squalid one, and which one the filthy?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet,that's another good example though as I've seen immaculately-maintained 30-year-old cars, and they're capable of being covered in mud there's always room for something a little different. Conversely your new merc may have a litter bin of a back seat or have just returned from a horse show with enough mud and worse to attain "squalid" all this just adds colour to the point in the answer though - *think, and choose appropriately*.

Comment: Just find the word that means what you want, without needing a modifier. Capiche?

Comment: @ChrisH - That's a good point. I was picturing a car that looked something like [this](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Salt_coverd_car_during_winter_P1020038.jpg) – very dirty, but not squalid. Put some half-eaten bags of fast food in the back seat, though, and, voilà: a squalid automobile.

Comment: @J.R. That's worse than mine! Then it would be filthy and squalid.